# Determine if User can elevate a process with c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, privileges

My application needs a function to check if the Current User is allowed to elevate a process (run as Admin). The function `IsUserAnAdmin()` does only tell me if the process is already elevated but in my case it is not.

Are there any other options to determine if the User is able to elevate a Process (is an admin)?

Comment: Any user is allowed to elevate a process, providing they know the admin password.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, just out of curiosity: Does Windows provide a mechanism similar to a sudoers list in Unix/Linux, such that only certain users are allowed to gain higher privileges?

Comment: @andreee I think you just have to be an admin user.

Comment: why not rely on the systems to handle permissions ?

Comment: If you're an admin user but UAC is enabled you run with a low privileged token by default, but can elevate back to your full token at any time. If you're a regular user you can elevate by entering the credentials of an administrator account.

Comment: may be you want look for `TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE` of current token. - if you have `TokenElevationTypeLimited` - you are can elevate by uac as same user (without password), if you are `TokenElevationTypeFull` you are already elevated. and if you have `TokenElevationTypeDefault` - you or already elevated (look `TOKEN_ELEVATION`) because you are built-in admin or uac disabled in system. or, if you are not elevated, - you can not elevate under same user. but you still can elevate as another (admin) user, but need know password

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for check current elevation status we can query [`TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530718(v=vs.85).aspx) of current process with [`TokenElevationType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379626(v=vs.85).aspx) :

- `TokenElevationTypeFull` - we already run elevated.
- `TokenElevationTypeLimited` - we run under limited token, but have
  elevated linked token. this is usually admin account with interactive
  logon. we can elevate under **same** user.
- `TokenElevationTypeDefault` - we have no linked token. here exist 2
  case:

  1. we already elevated (for check this use
     [`TokenElevation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379626(v=vs.85).aspx)    and
     look for `TokenIsElevated` from [`TOKEN_ELEVATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530717(v=vs.85).aspx) ) this can be if we run under built-in admin account
     (`DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS` 500 ) which is not filtered, or UAC is    disabled in system.
  2. we run not under admin account. we
     can elevate in    this case also, but only under **another** account.
     for this need    know this account password

demo code:

```
inline ULONG BTE(BOOL f)
{
    return f ? 0 : GetLastError();
}

void TryElevate()
{
    WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    if (GetModuleFileNameW(0, path, RTL_NUMBER_OF(path)))
    {
        SHELLEXECUTEINFOW sei = { sizeof(sei), 0, 0, L"runas", path };
        ShellExecuteExW(&sei);
    }
}

ULONG CheckElevation()
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    ULONG err = BTE(OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken));
    if (!err)
    {
        ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 0x20;
        union {
            PTOKEN_USER ptu;
            PVOID buf;
        };
        static volatile UCHAR guz;
        PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
        PWSTR SzSid = 0;

        //++ for display user sid only
        do 
        {
            if (cb < rcb)
            {
                cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
            }

            if (!(err = BTE(GetTokenInformation(hToken, ::TokenUser, buf, cb, &rcb))))
            {
                ConvertSidToStringSidW(ptu->User.Sid, &SzSid);
                break;
            }

        } while (err == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);
        // -- for display user sid only

        union {
            TOKEN_ELEVATION te;
            TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE tet;
        };

        if (!(err = BTE(GetTokenInformation(hToken, ::TokenElevationType, &tet, sizeof(tet), &rcb))))
        {
            switch (tet)
            {
            case TokenElevationTypeDefault:
                if (!(err = BTE(GetTokenInformation(hToken, ::TokenElevation, &te, sizeof(te), &rcb))))
                {
                    if (te.TokenIsElevated)
                    {
                        // we are built-in admin or UAC is disabled in system
            case TokenElevationTypeFull:
                MessageBoxW(HWND_DESKTOP, L"we run elevated", SzSid, MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                break;
                    }

                    // we can not elevate under same user, but still can elevate under another admin account
                    // non admin account
                    TryElevate();
                    MessageBoxW(HWND_DESKTOP, L"Default", SzSid, MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                }

                break;


            case TokenElevationTypeLimited:
                // this mean that we have linked token, which is elevated. we can elevate under same user
                TryElevate();
                MessageBoxW(HWND_DESKTOP, L"Limited", SzSid, MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                break;

            default:
                MessageBoxW(HWND_DESKTOP, L"unknown elevation type", SzSid, MB_ICONWARNING);
                err = ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
            }
        }

        if (SzSid) LocalFree(SzSid);

        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }

    return err;
}
```

and result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the help of the comment by @RbMm, Ive created the following function to determine if the process can be elevated. *(Without a password)*

```
bool IsElevationPossible()
{
    TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE tokenElevationType;
    DWORD size;
    if (!GetTokenInformation(
        GetCurrentProcessToken(),
        TokenElevationType,
        &tokenElevationType,
        sizeof(tokenElevationType),
        &size))
        {
        // Log Error

        return false;
    }

    return tokenElevationType == TokenElevationTypeLimited;
}
```